# How do you organise your files/folders?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-management, dictionary, file-organization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Organized Dictionary structure?](https://superuser.com/questions/284375/organized-dictionary-structure)

I would like to know how do you organise your files/folder for downloads, documents, pictures, movies, etc

I have 3 drives as follows:

> - 1TB NAS Drive for media share (Movies, Pictures, Downloads)
> - 1 internal drive for OS
> - 1 internal drive for documents, downloads, pictures etc.

what does your folders structure look like? My hard drives is unorganized, what is recommended to organize it?

Comment: subjective and open-ended question, please read FAQ and this: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/

Answer (score 3):

i organize by category, type, name, then date

for example:

```
  videos 
tv shows    movies
--------------------
sci-fi      sci-fi
drama       comedy
mystery     intenational
cartoon     classics


    music
genre   genre    genre
------------------------
artist  artist   artist
  |       |        |
album   album    album
```

Answer (score 1):

This probably falls outside the allowable questions FAQ, but others can decide that.

Two approaches come to mind.  Categories/tagging and the Google  way.

By Categories I simply mean sorting things.  Movies, pictures, documents.  Then Action, Adventure or picture subject/date.  All very "normal".

By the Google way, I simply mean drop it all in one bucket and index it.  Find everything by searching.  Gmail made limited use of labels when first launched.  To find anything, you searched.  Since Vista/Win7 made searching ubiquitous on my desktop, I almost always use it to find things.

What are you most comfortable with?  Maybe a blend of the two.